# does jQuery ajaxComplete() detect prototypejs ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, magento, prototypejs

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){   
      $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
         console.log("finished")
      });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

this does not fire after a prototype call on the page.

But this prototype code is working:

```
Ajax.Responders.register({
  onCreate: function() {
    console.log("start")
  },
  onComplete: function() {
    console.log("finished")
  }
});
```

had issues with ajaxcomplete previously when multiple jquery libraries were loaded on the page but this is not the case now.

Does jQuery ajaxComplete() detect prototype ajax calls?

Thanks!

Comment: Take care that, since Magento is historically build on prototypeJS, $ is actually the prototypeJS lib, when there is a `$j = jQuery.noConflict();`already on Magento that could simplify your actual code. So `$('some')` -> a prototypeJS object, `$j('some')` -> a jQuery object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer : no

Long answer : because jQuery and PrototypeJS abstract the basic XHR functionality in different ways, they track the number of active XHR requests in their own way, and fire their own callbacks.

For instance in PrototypeJS the `activeRequestCount` is incremented or decremented when the ajax requests start or complete respectively

```
Ajax.Responders.register({
  onCreate:   function() { Ajax.activeRequestCount++ },
  onComplete: function() { Ajax.activeRequestCount-- }
});
```